# How can I get Word 2010 to show more styles than "Heading 1"?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

There's no way to select `Heading 2` (and higher). Suggestions on how to fix this are welcome.

It doesn't change when I creating documents from other templates.

Comment: Does the Heading 2 style exist? Has it been accidentally deleted?

Comment: I have no idea, but if it was deleted, how can I get it back? Is there a way to reset all styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in this case was caused by shared templates. Somehow the template got messed up, and all headings but Heading 1 were gone from the template.

Answer (score 30):

Word 2007 does the same, and it's really irritating.

Here's my style list on opening a new doc, not very helpful.
[image: Word 2007 "Styles" box showing "Clear All", "Heading 1" and "Normal" only]

Click the button at the bottom, the one on the right, to open the *"[image: Manage Styles icon] Manage Styles"*.

1. Click the **Recommend** tab
2. scroll to **Heading 1** and its friends, select those that you want visible and
3. click the **Show** button.
4. (optional) If you also select the **New documents based on this template** option at the bottom this change will happen for all new documents as well.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Word 2010 "Manage Styles" window, showing the steps described in the text]
[here's another one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JW6V.png)

Comment: This wasn't the problem, but it might help others

Comment: @Sander Damn. Did you have a look at the other tabs, in case there was anything there that was the cause? And so I take it that the problem was deeper than that style just lacking visibilty? Do you have any more specifics available?

Comment: awesome, that helped me out a lot

Comment: @DMA57361: you wrote _"to open the "Style Inspector""_ - but this is the _"Manage Styles"_ window, NOT _"Style Inspector"_. Anyway, your post was really useful, it helped me, too! +1 for that!

Comment: @sk8erpeter Your last screenshot didn't load, so I left the "ugly" one in. By the way, we love freehand circles around here.

Comment: @slhck: please look at this once more: http://superuser.com/posts/194112/revisions. It actually DOES load, I don't really understand your problem. :) Btw. "ugly" was not an offense, I just find the new screenshot easier to follow.

Comment: No wonder Steve Balmer got fired allowing everything to be moved around in Word 2007 and after

Comment: For anyone trying to find how to open the window in the first screenshot in Word 2010, it's under **Home > Change Styles**. You click the pop-out arrow at the bottom right of the Change Styles option. Took me a second to find that one :)

Answer (score 8):

Instead of changing the settings, you can simply do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> to get Heading 2, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> to get Heading 3, etc...

Comment: Thanks! This is much easier than changing the options (and there's no 'options' link in my Word 2010 anyway).

Answer (score 7):

In Word 2010 right click on the Styles ribbon (or left click on the arrow in the lower right of the Styles ribbon), select options, and then check the box "Show next heading when previous level is used".

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you've previously hidden a style explicitly. It seems like there's a hidden setting that gets toggled when you do that, that will prevent 'Hide Until Used' from working.

If this has been done in a template, you might find [this page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d70f5b3e-4d13-4a54-afe7-50c8c8422b95/manage-styles-dialog-and-hide-until-used?forum=word) helpful. There is a way to undo it but it involves unzipping the document and messing with XML. This is probably only worth it if your template has other settings that would be difficult or time-consuming to recreate. Content copied here, including spelling/grammar mistakes.

```
1. Open your document (*.docx) with '7-Zip'.
2. Navigate to 'word' folder.

Modifying 'styles.xml' will do the hiding as default. Here I wanted to remove Heading 5 and 6.

3. Extract 'styles.xml' and open it on a text editor (such as Notepad++)
4. Find w:styleId="Heading5" and remove the '<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:styleId="Heading5"> ... </w:style>' node.

Do the similar for heading 6.

5. Find w:styleId="Heading5Char" and remove the '<w:style w:type="character" w:customStyle="1" w:styleId="Heading6Char"> ... </w:style>' node.

Do the similar for heading 6.

6. Save 'styles.xml' and replace the existing 'styles.xml' in 7-zip (by drag and drop).

That's it.. Close the 7-zip window and open the file.
```

I had to do this for every style starting with `Heading 3`, to get `Heading 3` to show up as the 'next style'. Note that this will wipe out any formatting changes you've made to these styles previously.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above helped me.  I was, however, able to solve this issue by explicitly adding [Style] to the quick action tool bar. Then I was able to type the style name and invoke it that way. The [Style**s**] vice [Style] button does not allow explicit typing (entry) of the style name.